# RBAC in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm using asp .net idneitty and duende identity server so i have 2 tables in my data base ASPNETROLES and ApiScope (api1.read ,api1.write , .....) my probleme is that i want to assign those scopes to specific role but i dont figure out the best way of storing the data. i think to create a custome table with columns(roleId,ScopeId,permission) is that correct or there is a better solution

```
--------------------------------------
| RoleID | ScopeID | Permission      |
--------------------------------------
|   1    |    1    |   api1.read     |
|   1    |    2    |   api2.write    |
|   2    |    1    |   api1.read     |
|   2    |    3    |   api3.write    |
|   3    |    2    |   api.read     |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Shouldn't identity server configure the table automatically?

Comment: how is that possible